# How to return false in javascript function from JQuery calling [web method] in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

So in default.aspx I have the code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() 
            {     

        test();
        //here should return true or false and exit validateForm so not to run InsertUpdateData()

    InsertUpdateData()

        }

  </script>     


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

(function test() {
    var areaId = 98;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GridViewData.aspx/GetRegions",
        data: "{areaId:" + areaId + "}",
        //data:99 ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function artybones(data) {
            // alert(data.d);
            if (data.d == "Foo 98")
            { alert("its true"); }
            else
            { alert("its false"); }

        }
    });
});     

</script>
```

in GridViewData.aspx I have

```
<script runat="server">     

    [WebMethod]     
    public static string GetRegions(int areaId)     
    {        
        return "Foo " + areaId;     
    } 

    </script>
```

When I call test() from javascript i want it to return false but cant seem to geta value from test. Can someone post the code to do this? I know i am close..thanks in advance to those who post..

Comment: Do you find your question readable? I don't. Did you read the [formatting tips](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (The orange question mark)?

Comment: looks good now. I will re read the formatting tips..sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wrap your test function in a DOM ready. You also don't name the function for your ajax success because you are defining the function at the time you create it. Finally, you have your `data:` parameter on your ajax call messed up. You have the curly braces in quotes, when they should be outside the JSON data. Like `{ areaId: areaId }` With this you are setting a parameter on a JSON object. You are calling that parameter "areaId" and you are setting it equal to a variable you have also called areaId. There is nothing wrong with this, but if it's confusing to set areaId to areaId then change your variable name in the javascript `var clientAreaId = 98;` then it would be easier to read and understand `{ areaId: clientAreaId }`

Do this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function test() {
    var areaId = 98;
    var isTrue = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "GridViewData.aspx/GetRegions",
        data: { areaId: areaId },
        //data:99 ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            // alert(data.d);
            if (data.d == "Foo 98")
            { alert("its true");
              isTrue = true; }
            else
            { alert("its false");
              isTrue = false; }
        }
    });
    return isTrue;
}    

</script>
```

Then in your call to test do this:

```
if (test() == true)
    InsertUpdateData();
```

You don't need to wrap named functions in DOM ready because they aren't executed until they are called. However, if you were calling `test()` when the page loaded then I would wrap that call in a DOM ready:

`$(test);`

Lastly, follow Guffa's suggestion of turning your request into a synchronous request by adding async: false to the parameters in your ajax call.

Comment: I don't see your `test()` function returning anything.  Also, `$(test());` would evaluate immediately, not at domReady.  You would want to leave out the parens so as to pass a function reference: `$(test);`.

Comment: Gentleman thank you. I am always amazed at the quick responses here. You guys are the best. For the most part your changes have helped me. The only thing was because I was calling a method on another page with some string value I still needed the data: "{areaId:" + areaId + "}", to get the code to work properly. I still have some cleanup but the advice you gave me got me over the issue i was having. Thanks again to all..

Comment: Ah ok. I guess I'm just used to MVC and model binding. Makes sense. Don't forget to accept ;)

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX call is asynchronous, so the function ends before the result arrives. The success function runs later, when the result arrives.

Change the AJAX request to be synchronous, to get the result before the function exists, by adding an async property to the `ajax` call:

```
async: false,
```

Comment: -1 Don't recommend synchronous ajax. It's the bane of all evil.

Comment: @Raynos: It's the only possible way to make the function return the result of the server call.

Comment: Guffa is correct. The way the OP wants his function to work, it needs to be synchronous. However, I agree with you Raynos in that the entire thing should be re-factored to take advantage of asynchronous ajax calls but that was not what the question asked.

Comment: @Guffa It is indeed the only way to make this work but it's still never correct to have synchronous ajax. The correct answer is always to refactor it so it works asynchronously.

Comment: @Raynos: That's a generalization. If it was always wrong to do a synchronous call it wouldn't even be included in the jQuery library.

Comment: @Guffa it's indeed a generalisation but I doubt in this particular the user was doing something that warranted synchronous ajax loading.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a slightly different approach.
When i do ajax calls using jquery i use the success and the error functions.

To make your ajax call end up in the error function you should make asp return a different http status code. I use status code 400 for this which means,

> 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by
>   the server due to malformed syntax.
>   The client SHOULD NOT repeat the
>   request without modifications.

Explanation status code can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Here's and example i used today inside a colorbox:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: $(formSelector, '#cboxLoadedContent').serializeArray(),
  success: function() {
    $.colorbox.close();
    window.location.href = successurl;
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    $('ul.errors', '#cboxLoadedContent').html(errorThrown);
    $.colorbox.resize();
  }
});
```

I'm not familiar with asp but this is how my php + symfony template error handling looks like 
(this sets the 400 and add errors which will be catched by my ajax call)

```
<?php
if ($sf_request->hasErrors()) {
  $errors = array();
  foreach ($sf_request->getErrors() as $error) {
    $errors[] = msI18N::translate($error);
  }

  sfContext::getInstance()->getResponse()->setStatusCode(400, '<li>' . implode('<li></li>', $errors) . '</li>');
}
?>
```

Hope this example give's you and idea how you could pull it off using asp.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want to return true where you have `alert("its true")`.  Based on that premise, you will want to do one of two things:

**Option 1.**  Use a synchronous ajax call.  You would set a variable in your success function indicating the return value, and then return that value after the ajax call:

```
function test() {
    var areaId = 98;
    var returnVal;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,     //  Make it synchronous here
        type: "POST",
        url: "GridViewData.aspx/GetRegions",
        data: "{areaId:" + areaId + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function artybones(data) {
            returnVal = data.d == "Foo 98";  // set the return value
        }
    });
    return returnVal;   // return true or false
}
```

Then, check the result of `test()` to determine whether to call `InsertUpdateData()`:

```
if (test())
{
    InsertUpdateData();
}
```

**Option 2.**  Call `InsertUpdateData()` from the success callback.  You can either pass it to `test()` as a parameter or hard code it in `test()`.  Here's the hard coded technique:

```
function test() {
    var areaId = 98;
    var returnVal;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GridViewData.aspx/GetRegions",
        data: "{areaId:" + areaId + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function artybones(data) {
            if(data.d == "Foo 98")
            {
                InsertUpdateData();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here's passing it as a parameter:

```
function test(fnDataMatch) {
    var areaId = 98;
    var returnVal;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GridViewData.aspx/GetRegions",
        data: "{areaId:" + areaId + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function artybones(data) {
            if(data.d == "Foo 98")
            {
                fnDataMatch();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then, call `test()` like so:

```
test(InsertUpdateData);
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the async alternative. Sync web calls should be the very last resort to any problem.